# IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.8(Liberty) + Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-security, websphere, appfuse

We have a sample web application built on appfuse starter kit version 2.2.1 which uses Spring security 3.1.3.RELEASE. We are going to deploy it on WAS 7 and we are testing it on IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.8(Liberty).
Our problem is after successful/failed login request some thing corrupts  the servletPath value of the request and sets it to null.

> ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()

This is the time when the LocaleFilter tries to do chain.doFilter using /j_security_check value for getServletPath() and we encounter :

> Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.getRequestPath:116' 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>   at org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.getRequestPath(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:116)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:100)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.matches(DefaultSecurityFilterChain.java:42)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:203)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:59)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
>   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
>   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at ir.dpi.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:67)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]
>   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
>   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
>   at [internal classes]

This is our security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none"/>

<http auto-config="false" create-session="always">
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao" >
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
            <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource"
    p:userPropertyToUse="username"/>


<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.removeUser(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution using [this code ranch topic](http://www.coderanch.com/t/571164/Websphere/Websphere-Commerce-Java-filter-Struts). AppFuse uses different Filters(javax.servlet) and the Wrapping mechanism of IBM WebSphere is sensitive to the session creation precedence. So I have moved Spring securityFilter mapping upward in the web.xml file.

```xml
     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
     </filter-mapping>

     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
     </filter-mapping>

     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
     ...
```

Now the Login process is done completely.

Please note that it is vital to set these settings in the Liberty server.xml:

```
<httpSession cookieName="MY_LIBERTY_COOKIE" />
<basicRegistry />
```

The equivalent settings in the IBM WebSphere Application Server(WAS Full) is set in:

> Session management -> General Properties -> Enable cookies

Also  in WAS version 7 (may apply to other versions) it is required to use:

> ```
> <http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" create-session="always">
> ```

in the spring security.xml file.