# Getting Firewalled Request Classcast exception at sessionMgmt filter in spring filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having the session mgmt filter in the spring filter chain throw this exception in this class HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository .
This is my snippet of my security-app.xml

```
<beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain1" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/resources/**" filters="none"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue, 
                customBadgeAuthFilter,   
                                                      logoutFilter,   

                                                         requestCacheFilter,
                                                         securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
                                                         sessionMgmtFilter,
                                                         formLoginExceptionTranslationFilter,
                                                         filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </beans:list>
```

`</beans:constructor-arg></beans:bean><beans:bean id="securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" 
class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter"/>
<beans:bean id="requestCacheFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter" />
    <beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue"
class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
<beans:property name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepository"/>
    </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="securityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/><beans:bean id="sessionMgmtFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
<beans:constructor-arg ref="securityContextRepository"/>
</beans:bean>`

It is a class cast when it is trying to cast to SavedContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper. This value is set by the ContextPersistentFilter which does get called in my security-chain as the first element

```
public void saveContext(SecurityContext context, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper responseWrapper = (SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper)response;
    // saveContext() might already be called by the response wrapper
    // if something in the chain called sendError() or sendRedirect(). This ensures we only call it
    // once per request.
    if (!responseWrapper.isContextSaved() ) {
        responseWrapper.saveContext(context);
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper
at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
at edu.mayo.fss.security.filter.SecureLoginFilter.doFilter(SecureLoginFilter.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
at edu.mayo.fss.spring.util.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:41)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
at
```

Can some please help out as to what I need to do to resolve this firewalled request classcast exception. The error starts in the sessionMgmtFilter when it tries to cast.

Thanks
DJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a secondary servlet filter before the spring-filter chain proxy.
The instant I got rid of that filter , everything started working. 
So if the spring-filter chain is not getting called directly from the jsp but is routed through another filter which then invokes the filter chain, the firewalled request will throw a Class Cast Exception. The customFilter before spring-security was the cause of the FirewalledClass Cast Exception.

```
<filter><filter-name>customFilter</filter-name><filter-class>sas.SecureLoginFilter</filter-class></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>customFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping><filter><filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class></filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some what the same problem and I have added the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868621/ibm-websphere-8-5-5-8liberty-spring-security-3-1-3-release/35990270#35990270).

May be it helps some body.